# Attempt to get length of null array exception

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

Whenever I call `getContentResolver().applyBatch(authority,batch)`, My app crashes on a Asus mobile, while it works fine on other android smartphones.

**Logcat**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.applyBatch(ContentProvider.java:288)
at android.content.ContentProviderClient.applyBatch(ContentProviderClient.java:377)
at android.content.ContentResolver.applyBatch(ContentResolver.java:1244)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

**What happens:**

You are calling [`ContentResolver.applyBatch()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#applyBatch(java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Candroid.content.ContentProviderOperation%3E)) with a null `operations` array, this is why you receive a `NullPointerException`.

This method expects this parameter not to be null, as shown by its signature:

```
public @NonNull ContentProviderResult[] applyBatch(@NonNull String authority, 
                                                   @NonNull ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> operations) 
                                                   throws RemoteException, OperationApplicationException
```

You should test the validity of your `batch` array before calling `applyBatch()`, and refrain from calling it should `batch` be null (assuming that having it null means there's no operation to apply).

**Why does it work on some cellphones and not on other?**

- Either because the list of operations to apply depends on the cellphone itself or its configuration (installed apps, Android API, stored data, anything...), which makes it null in the specific case of your Asus ;
- or because it works "by accident" on the other cellphones you have tested. This happens sometimes when the code does something wrong but without raising any error due to some permissivity you cannot rely on.

This depends on what your app does.